# Raise Event on another Form

Tags: vb.net

subject is declare event on Form1 , and run that event on Form2
here is the code , but event doesnt work on Form2 !! what is missing here??
many thanks

**Form1**:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnOpenForm2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenForm2.Click
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub

    Public Event show_My_Message()
    Private Sub btnShowMessageOnForm2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowMessageOnForm2.Click
        RaiseEvent show_My_Message()
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Form2**:

```
Public Class Form2

    Public WithEvents My_Form1 As Form1 = New Form1
    Private Sub Show_My_Message_On_Form2() Handles My_Form1.show_My_Message
        MsgBox("Hello")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You need to specify which instance of `Form2`. It's just a class, after all. As far as the framework knows, you could have many instances.

Comment: does that mean like this (     Dim My_Form2 As New Form2
        My_Form2.Show()) I try it but still not raise event

Comment: Nope. This `Public WithEvents My_Form1 As Form1 = New Form1` declares a new Form1 that is not the instance you have already on screen. Pass the current instance of Form1 to Form2 in a Constructor (e.g., `dim f2 As New Form2() f2.Show(Me)`), then use `AddHandler` to add a handler to the event. -- You have to add this Constructor (`Public Sub New(f1 as Form1)`), it doesn't generate by itself. Don't remove the empty Constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `dim f2 As New Form2(Me) f2.Show()` -- The other form is also valid (but it's not what I was describing, it *slipped* over), but that sets the Owner of Form2, which you'd have to cast to Form1 (e.g., `dim f1 = DirectCast(Me.Owner, Form1)`), which is a *blind* cast.

Comment: Sorry sir is it possible to edit the above code i submitted, many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what Jimi was talking about, using the `.Owner` property.

Form1:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnOpenForm2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenForm2.Click
        Form2.Show(Me) ' <-- Pass Form1 into Form2 via Show()
    End Sub

    Public Event show_My_Message()
    Private Sub btnShowMessageOnForm2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowMessageOnForm2.Click
        RaiseEvent show_My_Message()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Form2:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private WithEvents My_Form1 As Form1

    Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        If Not IsNothing(Me.Owner) AndAlso Me.Owner Is Form1 Then
            My_Form1 = DirectCast(Me.Owner, Form1)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub F1_show_My_Message() Handles My_Form1.show_My_Message
        MessageBox.Show("Hello")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it without cross form event handling,

Form1

```
Public MyForm2 As Form2
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If MyForm2 Is Nothing Then
        MyForm2 = New Form2
    End If
    MyForm2.Show()
    MyForm2.Show_My_Message_On_Form2("Hello")
End Sub
```

Form2

```
Public Class Form2

    Public Sub Show_My_Message_On_Form2(theMess As String)
        MessageBox.Show(theMess)
    End Sub

End Class
```